# Delete Reminder from Database on End Date

Tags: java, android, sqlite, alarm, reminders

Working with `Reminders` taking two dates from user, first `Start` Reminder Date and second `End` Reminder Date

I have `successfully` written a code to `start` a reminder, `repeat` the reminder and now I would like to know **How can I remove the reminder when comes to End date from database ?**

I know, I have to use something like below to `cancel an alarm` (to **delete** reminder from database) but don't know where to use same code to **delete reminder based on End date** provided with reminder, click on [link](https://github.com/blanyal/Remindly/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blanyal/remindme/MainActivity.java) to see Activity code

```
for (int i = IDmap.size(); i >= 0; i--) {

       int id = IDmap.get(i);

       // Get reminder from reminder database using id
       Reminder temp = rb.getReminder(id);

       // Delete reminder
       rb.deleteReminder(temp);

       // Delete reminder alarm
       mAlarmReceiver.cancelAlarm(getApplicationContext(), id);
}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java:**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int mReceivedID = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(ReminderEditActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID));

        // Get notification title from Reminder Database
        ReminderDatabase rb = new ReminderDatabase(context);
        Reminder reminder = rb.getReminder(mReceivedID);
        String mTitle = reminder.getTitle();

        // Create intent to open ReminderEditOldActivity on notification click
        Intent editIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderEditActivity.class);
        editIntent.putExtra(ReminderEditActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(mReceivedID));
        PendingIntent mClick = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mReceivedID, editIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Create Notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_on_white_24dp)
                .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setTicker(mTitle)
                .setContentText(mTitle)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentIntent(mClick)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nManager.notify(mReceivedID, mBuilder.build());
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, int ID) {
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Put Reminder ID in Intent Extra
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(ReminderEditActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(ID));
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // Calculate notification time
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long currentTime = c.getTimeInMillis();
        long diffTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime;

        // Start alarm using notification time
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + diffTime,
                mPendingIntent);

        // Restart alarm if device is rebooted
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    public void setRepeatAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, int ID, long RepeatTime) {
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Put Reminder ID in Intent Extra
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(ReminderEditActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(ID));
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // Calculate notification timein
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long currentTime = c.getTimeInMillis();
        long diffTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime;

        // ensure the next alarm is in the future
        while(diffTime < 0) {
            diffTime += RepeatTime;
        }

        // Start alarm using initial notification time and repeat interval time
        mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + diffTime,
                RepeatTime , mPendingIntent);

        // Restart alarm if device is rebooted
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context, int ID) {
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Cancel Alarm using Reminder ID
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
        mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent);

        // Disable alarm
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

**BootReceiver.java:**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String mTitle;
    private String mTime;
    private String mDate;
    private String mRepeatNo;
    private String mRepeatType;
    private String mActive;
    private String mRepeat;
    private String[] mDateSplit;
    private String[] mTimeSplit;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mHour, mMinute, mDay, mReceivedID, mEndDay, mEndMonth, mEndYear;
    private long mRepeatTime;
    private String mEndDate;
    private String[] mEndDateSplit;

    private Calendar mCalendar, mEndCalendar;
    private AlarmReceiver mAlarmReceiver;

    // Constant values in milliseconds
    private static final long milMinute = 60000L;
    private static final long milHour = 3600000L;
    private static final long milDay = 86400000L;
    private static final long milWeek = 604800000L;
    private static final long milMonth = 2592000000L;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

            ReminderDatabase rb = new ReminderDatabase(context);
            mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            mEndCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            mAlarmReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();

            List<Reminder> reminders = rb.getAllReminders();

            for (Reminder rm : reminders) {
                mReceivedID = rm.getID();
                mRepeat = rm.getRepeat();
                mRepeatNo = rm.getRepeatNo();
                mRepeatType = rm.getRepeatType();
                mActive = rm.getActive();
                mDate = rm.getDate();
                mTime = rm.getTime();
                mEndDate = rm.getmEndDate();

                mDateSplit = mDate.split("/");
                mTimeSplit = mTime.split(":");

                mEndDateSplit = mEndDate.split("/");

                mDay = Integer.parseInt(mDateSplit[0]);
                mMonth = Integer.parseInt(mDateSplit[1]);
                mYear = Integer.parseInt(mDateSplit[2]);

                mEndDay = Integer.parseInt(mEndDateSplit[0]);
                mEndMonth = Integer.parseInt(mEndDateSplit[1]);
                mEndYear = Integer.parseInt(mEndDateSplit[2]);

                mHour = Integer.parseInt(mTimeSplit[0]);
                mMinute = Integer.parseInt(mTimeSplit[1]);

                mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, --mMonth);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, --mEndMonth);
                mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mEndYear);
                mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mEndDay);
                mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
                mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
                mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                // Cancel existing notification of the reminder by using its ID
                // mAlarmReceiver.cancelAlarm(context, mReceivedID);

                // Check repeat type
                if (mRepeatType.equals("Daily")) {
                    mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milDay;
                } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Every 2 Days")) {
                    mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milDay;
                } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Every 3 Days")) {
                    mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milDay;
                } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Weekly")) {
                    mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milWeek;
                } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Monthly")) {
                    mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milMonth;
                }

                // Create a new notification
                if (mActive.equals("true")) {
                    if (mRepeat.equals("true")) {
                        mAlarmReceiver.setRepeatAlarm(context, mCalendar, mReceivedID, mRepeatTime);
                    } else if (mRepeat.equals("false")) {
                        mAlarmReceiver.setAlarm(context, mCalendar, mReceivedID);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int mReceivedID = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(ReminderEditActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID));

        // Get notification title from Reminder Database
        ReminderDatabase rb = new ReminderDatabase(context);
        Reminder reminder = rb.getReminder(mReceivedID);

        String[] s = mEndDateSplit = mEndDate.split("/");
        int mEndDay = Integer.parseInt(mEndDateSplit[0]);
        int mEndMonth = Integer.parseInt(mEndDateSplit[1]);
        int mEndYear = Integer.parseInt(mEndDateSplit[2]);

        int mHour = Integer.parseInt(mTimeSplit[0]);
        int mMinute = Integer.parseInt(mTimeSplit[1]);

        Calendar mEndCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, --mEndMonth);
        mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mEndYear);
        mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mEndDay);
        mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
        mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
        mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        String mRepeatNo = reminder.getRepeatNo();

        if (mRepeatType.equals("Daily")) {
            mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milDay;
        } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Every 2 Days")) {
            mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milDay;
        } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Every 3 Days")) {
            mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milDay;
        } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Weekly")) {
            mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milWeek;
        } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Monthly")) {
            mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milMonth;
        }

        if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() < mEndCalendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
            String mTitle = reminder.getTitle();

            // Create intent to open ReminderEditOldActivity on notification click
            Intent editIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderEditActivity.class);
            editIntent.putExtra(ReminderEditActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(mReceivedID));
            PendingIntent mClick = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mReceivedID, editIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            // Create Notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_on_white_24dp)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setTicker(mTitle)
                    .setContentText(mTitle)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setContentIntent(mClick)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

            NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nManager.notify(mReceivedID, mBuilder.build());
        }

        if (reminder.getRepeat().equals("true")) {
            if( SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mRepeatTime > mEndCalendar.getTimeInMillis()){
                // The next alert will happen after the end time, cancel it and delete it from the database.
                cancelAlarm(context, mReceivedID);
                rb.deleteReminder(reminder);
            }
        } else {
            // The alert isn't set to be repeated, cancel and delete it from the database.
            cancelAlarm(context, mReceivedID);
            rb.deleteReminder(reminder);
        }

    }
```

Comment: In your `AlarmReceiver.onReceive(....)` you can check to see if the current reminder is the last one (there is no reminder after this one until the end time) and cancel the alarm if that is true.

Comment: @Titus yeah I tried in a same way but did not get any success, I think I used the wrong approach, show me the code you would like me to add in my class

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've meant in the comment I've posted.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ReminderDatabase rb = new ReminderDatabase(context);
        Reminder reminder = rb.getReminder(mReceivedID);
        .......
        if(rm.getRepeat().equals("true")){
            String[] s = mEndDateSplit = mEndDate.split("/");
            int mEndDay = Integer.parseInt(mEndDateSplit[0]);
            int mEndMonth = Integer.parseInt(mEndDateSplit[1]);
            int mEndYear = Integer.parseInt(mEndDateSplit[2]);

            int mHour = Integer.parseInt(mTimeSplit[0]);
            int mMinute = Integer.parseInt(mTimeSplit[1]);

            Calendar mEndCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, --mEndMonth);
            mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mEndYear);
            mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mEndDay);
            mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
            mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
            mEndCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            String mRepeatNo = rm.getRepeatNo();

            if (mRepeatType.equals("Daily")) {
                mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milDay;
            } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Every 2 Days")) {
                mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milDay;
            } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Every 3 Days")) {
                mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milDay;
            } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Weekly")) {
                mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milWeek;
            } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Monthly")) {
                mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milMonth;
            }

            if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mRepeatTime > nEndCalendar.getTimeInMills()) {
                // The next alert will happen after the end time, cancel it and delete it from the database.
                cancelAlarm(context, mReceivedID);
                rb.deleteReminder(mReceivedID);
            }
        }else{
            // The alert isn't set to be repeated, cancel and delete it from the database.
            cancelAlarm(context, mReceivedID);
            rb.deleteReminder(mReceivedID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sun No, in `AlarmReceiver` you need to do this check when you receive an alarm, you need to check if this alarm should be the last one.

Comment: @Sun Yes I know but the `AlarmReceiver` is the one that receives a broadcast when one of the alarms that you've set is triggered. That is when you need to check if you should cancel the alarm. In the other `BroadcastReceiver` you need to check if you should set an alert so I guess you will have to add a check in `BootReceiver` as well.

Comment: ok got it so you mean my AlarmReceiver class code would look like this: http://pastebin.com/DXDVxnXc

Comment: now even not triggering Reminders I have created... it was working earlier, See the UDPATED section above

Comment: @Sun it should be `if( SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mRepeatTime > mEndCalendar.getTimeInMillis())` instead of `<` use `>` which means that if the future alarm is after the end time, cancel the alarm.

Comment: tried yet not done, even not getting Reminder triggers